# access - Only append unique results

Tags: database, ms-access

I have a system where new users can be added, and i want to make a query that checks to see if there are duplicate results with the same Name_ID and only adds the unique results. (More explained below)

**Table1**

```
Name_ID ¦ Name
-------------------
1       ¦ Michael
2       ¦ Rebecca
3       ¦ Sammy
```

**Table2**

```
Name_ID ¦ Name
-------------------
1       ¦ Michael
2       ¦ Rebecca
```

These are in two separate database files as Table2 is supposed to be an archive.
What i want to do is to use a query ONLY to append the Name_ID's that are unique from table1 to table2, i.e. only appending 3 but leaving out Name_ID 1 and 2.

One last thing, i dont want to use SQL for this solution but would like to know if MS-Access has any in-built features that can solve this.

EDIT: Apparently there is no solution for without SQL so how would this be achieved with SQL?

Comment: If you *really* want to avoid SQL, you could use Recordset loops and .Find methods. But that would be silly - in a database, SQL should always be the method of choice, if possible.

Answer (score 2):

You should use this query:

```
INSERT INTO Table2(Name_ID, Name)  
SELECT Name_ID, Name  
FROM Table1 LEFT JOIN Table2 ON Table1.Name_ID = Table2.Name_ID  
WHERE Table2.Name_ID IS NULL
```

either, make a query or use Docmd.RunSQL command

Answer (score 1):

The MS Access built-in feature to prevent duplicates is a No Duplicates index on the field. 
A primary key is a type of such an index. These indexes will prevent insertion of a record in case of a duplicate value on the indexed field.
Please see more [here](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Create-and-use-an-index-to-improve-performance-0A8E2AA6-735C-4C3A-9DDA-38C6C4F1A0CE)